# App is crashing now while using firebase-storage, but worked fine for more than 1 month

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-crash-reporting

I developed a Android app, which is using firebase storage since 1 month. Yesterday I added another app to the same firebase projekt and today I got many exeptions and I have no idea what is causing the problem :/

I got this exeption, but the app is not crashing:

```
    Exception com.google.firebase.storage.StorageException: The operation retry limit has been exceeded.
    com.google.android.gms.internal.zzanv.zza ()
    com.google.firebase.storage.zzb.run ()
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
    java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:818)
    Caused by java.net.SocketException: Network subsystem is unavailable
    com.google.android.gms.internal.zzanv.zzfb ()
    com.google.android.gms.internal.zzanv.zza ()
    com.google.android.gms.internal.zzanm.zza ()
    com.google.android.gms.internal.zzanm.zzd ()
    com.google.firebase.storage.zzb.run ()
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
    java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:818)
```

EDIT:

It was just a network-timeout. ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should catch and handle the [StorageException](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageException). The downlaoded content is not available and that is causung the crash. Check if you have updated any paths you are trying to download.

Check the StorageException.ErrorCode for more details.

Comment: thank you, but I tested it and I can still download the files or check their status :/ How can I check if the quota limit was hit?